# Vector operator [ ] return value

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword

I'm currently working with a 2d vector representation of a table, like so:

```
vector< vector< myStruct > > table
```

myStruct is a class I have made. Right now, I am making a variable of type myStruct, and setting it equal to a value from the table. I'm doing the following inside of a for loop.

```
myStruct object = table[i][j];
```

I know that `operator []` for a vector returns a reference, but since I'm declaring a new instance of myStruct, is something actually being copied into object?

I'm wondering if doing something like the following would be different from what I have above:

```
myStruct & object = table[i][j];
```

Would this prevent something from being copied, making object only a reference to something from the table, or are both of these doing essentially the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Right on both counts. The first one copies into the object being created. The second one does not copy; it creates a reference to the array element.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that operator [] for a vector returns a reference, but since I'm declaring a new instance of myStruct, is something actually being copied into object?

Yes.

> ```
> myStruct & object = table[i][j];
> ```
>
> Would this prevent something from being copied, making object only a reference to something from the
>   table, or are both of these doing essentially the same thing?

They are not the same;
`object` references an element inside `table`.

Be careful not to erase the referenced element, or else it will dangle.